# angular 2 start and stop mechanism

Tags: angular, for-loop

In my mailing application, I send emails using preload list of email addresses and using function with loop inside to auto send emails

```
startEmailing() {

      var headers = new Headers();

      headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
      headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');

      for (var i = this.emails.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        var message = {

        mail_driver: this.mail_driver,
        mail_host: this.mail_host,
        mail_port: this.mail_port,
        mail_encryption: this.mail_encryption,
        mail_username: this.mail_username,
        mail_password: this.mail_password,
        email_body: this.email_body,
        email_subject: this.email_subject,

        email: this.emails[i],
        attachments: this.uploadedFiles

      }

      this.http
      .post(this.api_server_postSingpleEmail, JSON.stringify(message), {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        response => {

          if(response.success) {

            this.emails[response.data.email.id].status = true;

          }  else {

            this.msgs = [];
            this.msgs.push({severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Sending message for ' + this.emails[response.data.email.id].name + ' has failed.'});

            this._log += this.emails[response.data.email.id].name + "\n";
            console.log(this._log);

          }

        },
        err => {console.log(err)})
      }
    }
```

The question is, how can I implement a start stop mechanism on buttons? So let's say I've sent 50 emails and click stop, the loop will stop and wait for me to click on start button again to continue sending ?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case of RxJS.

Comment: but the for loop is too fast to stop